# Custom Cell in UITableView programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a UITableView which gets loaded with data from a MutableArray. The thing is, within this array I have many different attributes, therefore I would like to enter these attributes into a custom cell programmatically.

Also I would like to include a Slider within the Cell so there will need to be some sort of addition there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you've looked at tutorials, but have you checked out the "[UITableView construction, drawing and management (revisited)](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html)" post on http://cocoawithlove.com - this pretty much covers the full custom UITableViewCell gamut, including loading a custom view from a NIB.

Irrespective, one potential approach is to create your own custom cell that expends the UITableViewCell and simply add a UISlider property which you'd then set up within the `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` method and add it as a sub view via `[[self contentView] addSubview:yourUISlider];`, etc.

However, I'd be tempted to have a good look at the http://cocoawithlove.com article, and download the provided project as this will show you the available options in full.

Comment: I hadn't come across that post, that's an excellent project to look at for custom cells, now I get an idea. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Sandeep It's a great blog in general - recommended reading for all iOS/Cocoa fans. :-)